# Issue in making appear the div in the foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L08p1upt/)

Where i have

```
<div id="mulitplefileuploader" class="fileuploader">Upload</div>
<div id="status"></div>
```

in the html. In the Body i have the script that was in the fiddle and i have `$(".fileuploader").uploadFile(settings);` in the `document.ready`. All this will have only on file upload div,

If i am using a for loop say 5 times. It is not working I mean the div itself not appearing. As the for loop may have any count i can run the div in the for loop. But I should not have the same script in my html page (Because of few restrictions).

What shall i do to achieve my result. Allowing multiple div according to the html.

I tried here in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L08p1upt/2/) but it didn't succeed. How can i do this.

**Note  :** All the upload should work, the js don't know how many loop will appear in the html

### Update To run the code Here is the [chop](http://chopapp.com/#h3vvl3hd) and you shall try it [here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) in the display at html mode.

Comment: i dun understand, do you want to show the multiple 'Upload' buttons on page? But the plugin `hayageek/jquery-upload-file` already support selecting multiple files in the single 'Upload' button itself

Comment: use `append()` not `html()`. Where's the real code that is causing problems?You mentioned using forEach but never provided the example.  Without it this question doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: @Chinkang : I want to show upload in the table, where each file is uploaded for seperate tr td

Comment: @charlietfl i will give the php fiddle now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@reply to your comment: alright i see. If you take a look into the source code of the plugin, it has the missing `.each` to iterate all the retrieved selectors. so you can simply add one for it

```
$(".fileuploader").each(function(){ $(this).uploadFile(settings); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L08p1upt/4/

Comment: Thanks i am trying in the settimeout function, where i can't able to update the .each function.. (I have given my settimeout function in comment. can you please make it in that) http://jsfiddle.net/L08p1upt/5/

Comment: sorry i dont understand again, what is the purpose or objective for the settimeout?